# Webpacker in Rails 6 - Why do some default JS libraries have .start() methods?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, import, webpacker

When creating a new Rails 6 app, packs/application.js automatically includes the following:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

Why do the top 3 libraries have start methods that need to be manually called?

Comment: Because that's how they were designed? You can see what the `start` methods do, as to why they were designed that way, you'd have to ask them. My guess would be so that they could be included but have their startup controlled.